# Groovy generic method in intellij

Tags: generics, methods, intellij-idea, groovy

I'm converting java code to groovy.

Because of generic method, Intellij reports 'Cannot resolve symbol'.

Here is the code.

```
public interface SimpleCallback<T>{
    void accept(T result);
}

// Just remove throwable
public <V> LambdaCallback<V> test(SimpleCallback<V> callback){
    return new LambdaCallback<V>() {
        @Override
        void accept(Throwable thrown, V result) {
            callback.accept(result);
        }
    };
}
```

when I used this method like below, generic information disappeared. (Intellij)

```
// function parameter -> String id, LambdaCallback<Users> callback
userDB.find(uid, test(){
    result->
        result.name // "Cannot resolve symbol"

})

public class Users{
    public String name;
}
```

When I press ctrl + p in test(), It presents SimpleCallback callback (expected `SimpleCallback<Users>` callback)

I want to implicitly specify type, and I want to simplify callback.

Please help in solving this problem.

Comment: Groovy is a dynamic language unless you annotate things with `@CompileStatic` generics are (in general) ignored

Comment: The `@TypeChecked` annotation will also honor generics a bit more, though a bit less (I think) than `@CompileStatic`.